# Parametric action names in grails urlMappings

Tags: grails, urlmappings.groovy

I am trying to map a JSON api to my controller like:

/api/user/1/location GET --> Controller.getLocation()

/api/user/1/location POST --> Controller.setLocation()

I have tried the following url mapping rule without any luck:

```
    "/api/$controller/$id/$property" {
        action = {[GET: "get${params.property.capitalize()}", POST: "set${params.property.capitalize()}"]}
    }
```

Anyone tried something like this

Answer (score 2):

I tried and succeeded with both:

```
"/api/$controller/$id/$property"{
     action = {"get"+params.property.capitalize()}            //put all joint into the {} bracelet
}
```

and

```
"/api/$controller/$id/$property"{
     action = [GET: "getLocation", POST:"setLocation"]         //remove the {} bracelet
}
```

but failed to assign dynamic parameters into [GET:'',POST:''] map, for example:

```
"/api/$controller/$id/$property"{
     action = {["POST": "set"+params.property.capitalize(), "GET": "get"+params.property.capitalize()]}
}
```

and

```
"/api/$controller/$id/$property"{
     action = [POST: {"set"+params.property.capitalize()}, GET: {"get"+params.property.capitalize()}]
}
```

both produced a 404 error.

So I guess Grails only allow this kind of configuration to be static yet. Maybe somebody could dig into the source code to find out later.